# html5 doctype image padding-bottom bug

Tags: image, html, doctype

I've been making websites for a few years now, but only recently have I started using the html5 doctype and today I discovered the behaviour where a padding-bottom of 4px is added to images.

The padding disappears if you change the doctype to xhtml1.0

here is the simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Technic-Al</title>
    <style>
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#contain {
width: 900px;
background-color:#6C0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="contain">
<img src="images/head.gif" width="900" height="100" border="0" alt="head">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

changeing the doctype to any of the others removes the bottom-padding (green from the background)

Quite a few people have come on here to suggest the fix

line-height=0

I believe there is another fix that works as well.

Or should I say "work-around"

but surely this is a bug with the html5 doctype?

who do we speak to about it?
who deals with a bug like this?
how do we get it fixed?

Does anybody here know how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's what the CSS spec says should happen. It's not HTML5 specific, the `HTML 4.01 strict` and `XHTML 1.0 strict` doctypes will do the same thing.

It's not padding - it's the consequence of the computed height of the line box.

There's no hope of getting it changed, Too many web pages depend on the existing behaviour.

The appropriate authority for this is the [W3C CSS working group](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/members).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have scoured the net for this for weeks, but you answered exactly what I was after. I must say that I find a lot of  css counter-intuitive and hard to get my head around, even after working with it for years. I have now included img{display:block;} as part of my normal css reset.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where page was showing padding in bottom of page

```
img { display:block ; }
```

writing above in css file solved my problem. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Use the `vertical-align` property in your css :

```
img{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work-around. It doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: From what I can see, the popular work-around is img{display:block}. I still don't see why we need a work around. I'm just trying to find out how we get this addressed, and who by.